# .tfignore is not ignoring files

Tags: c#, tfs, version-control, tfignore

I have a .tfIgnore file like below whihc is already checked-in

```
\xx.Phoenix.Web\bower_components
\xx.Phoenix.Web\node_modules
*.autogen.cs
```

I would expect that everyfile which is match with `.autogen.cs` be ignored.
But the problem is when files are generated by t4 templates, file are shown in pending changes, see below picture, `xx.autogen.cs` is recognized as `add`

[image]

even I tried below but still not working

```
Phoenix\Domain\Entities\*.autogen.cs
```

and

```
\Phoenix\Domain\Entities\*.autogen.cs
```

We are using Vs2013 + Tfs2017

Comment: Are you using local or server workspaces?

Comment: @DanielMann local workspace

Comment: Where did you place the ignore file? Under the root of the workspace?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Yes

Answer (score 9):

First, please make sure your `.tfignore` file created without any problem. This file does **not have any suffix**. Details of how to take a look at my reply in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768954/visual-studio-2015-tfs-tfignore-file).

Also check if the files already in source control. If they are, `.tfignore` won't apply to them.

A way to solve the issue is updating your VS to **[VS2015Update 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/)**. The .tfignore should be working correctly. You could give a try with this version which have some improvements with tfignore.

More  ways for handling the issue you can refer this blog from GitHub: [Things in ".tfignore" still are shown in pending changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18)

Comment: Thanks for answer, .tfIgonre is created from "exclude files" context menu, and it's under source control. The only thing is we are using vs2013 in our company and we can't update to vs2015Update3 right now, so it seems that it's a known issue?

Comment: If the `.tfignore` works with  other files and folders just not work with @RezaRahmati `*.autogen.cs`.  Maybe it's the defects of Team Explorer and  VS for 2013 version. Give a try with this workaround add an `$` char into the entities folder name. TFS does not allow the $ character in the file name, so it can't be added to source control.  Otherwise, you may have to manually exclude this file for now.

Comment: That link to the cited Git Hub blog is invalid. Assume you mean this link with the same document title: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18

Comment: `Also check if the files already in source control. If they are, .tfignore won't apply to them.` - Is it possible to ignore such files anyway?

Comment: @neleus For this kind of files, you need to delete/destroy those files in source control, then check in the `.tfingore` file. Next time when you check in the files again, it will also auto excluded in VS IDE.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot delete them in tfs. My files are configs and needed for deploy

Answer (score 9):

Go to *Source Control Explorer* and delete the folder or file which you want to ignore.

Comment: I did it before, it wasn't working, the issue was for using vs2013, now we are using vs2017 and it's working as expected

Comment: This worked in my environment - normally, I would expect this to delete the files from the disk, but they remained, and were excluded from tf