# TFS Connectivity and Ignore Issues

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfignore

I am having some trouble with TFS:

1. I have ignore rules for certain files. For example:

\Build\Scripts*.sum

It does not seem to recognize this. But, if I exclude these files in the Visual Studio UI, it remembers that I excluded them for some time.Then I lose connectivity and I have to re-exclude them. Why doesnt the tfignore file seem to be working. This leads to:

2. I routinely lose the ability to connect to TFS. Ill be moving along happily working. then Ill go and check in some code and I will get the error that I do not have access to TFS. If I restart Visual Studio, I can then successfully connect and check in code. Things will be fine for a few hours, and then it will happen again. Why do I lose the ability to connect? And why does restarting fix it?

Comment: Hi Ethan, any update on this case, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that TFS thought these items had been "added" although that was not entirely clear from Visual Studio UI. I had to go to the Source Control Explorer and look at the folder where these files were. They were listed as 'add' which is how I figured this out. I never explicitly added these files. I had to right click on these items and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure you were using the correctly `.tfignore` file.**  This file does **not have any suffix**. One way to create it, suggest you to rename a new.txt file with `"tfignore."` It will auto change to right .tfignore file.

You can also use the **auto automatically generated .tfignore file**, follow below steps in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784750/5391065) here.

More detail info about the `.tfignore` file please refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server#tfignore-file-rules).

***Note:*** This `.tfignore` file will not affect with those files already in source control. You need to remove them from source control first. Also make sure your .tfignore files have checked in source control.

2. That sounds wired. `get the error that I do not have access to TFS` what's the detail error here? If restart Visual Studio, can then successfully connect and check in code. It shouldn't be a permission related issue.

One possibility is network related, double check and confirm if there is any instability of your network environment. If you are behind VPN, try to connect without VPN.

Since Restart Visual Studio fixed the issue, it also may related to cache. Try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), which may do the trick.