# TFS Eclipse throws an error "The character 0x007c ('|') is not permitted in server paths" after updating visual studio for mac to support iPad OS 13

Tags: eclipse, tfs, xamarin.ios

We have updated the latest visual studio for mac to support our iOS app (Xamarin) in iPad OS 13 which is recently released by Apple. After the update, we are getting the following error in eclipse while detecting the local changes to check-in.

```
The character 0x007c ('|') is not permitted in server paths '$/<path_to_product>/.vs/<project_name>/xs/project-cache/ProjectName-Debug|iPhone.json'.
```

It seems to be the file name ("ProjectName-Debug|iPhone.json") with a pipe symbol that is not supported in TFS. But the file is auto-generated by the IDE (Visual studio for mac, Xcode 11) and it contains the following information (ProjectReferences, MetadataReferences, Added files with path, BuildActions, etc...). There are two files that exist with the pipe symbol. One is for the actual device and another one is for the simulator.

- ProjectName-Debug|iPhone.json
- ProjectName-Debug|iPhoneSimulator.json

Does anyone face this issue? How to resolve it.

**Below are the version details.**

- Mac OS 10.14.6
- Eclipse 4.7.3
- Xcode 11
- Visual Studio for Mac 8.2.6

Thanks in advance.

**Quick fix:** Currently we are manually deleting those files while committing the changes. Again it will regenerate automatically.

Comment: Even we are facing the same issue after the latest VS update.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Git. What does your gitignore looks like?

Comment: @Saamer Thanks for your reply, we are not using git. We are using the "TFS" plugin in eclipse which is VSTS (Cloud repository). Also, we tried adding ".tpignore" in the root directory of our project, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For local workspace, you should use `.tfignore`  file to ignore files.  Such as

```
# Ignore the NuGet packages folder in the root of the repository.
# If needed, prefix 'packages' with additional folder names if it's 
# not in the same folder as .tfignore.
packages

# include package target files which may be required for msbuild,
# again prefixing the folder name as needed.
!packages/*.targets
```

As for how to generate this file, please refer my answer in this question: [Visual Studio 2015 TFS .tfignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768954/visual-studio-2015-tfs-tfignore-file/36784750#36784750)

**Note:** This .tfignore file will not affect with those files already in source control.

Manually delete those files while committing the changes. Then make sure your .tfignore files has checked in source control.  Next time when those files auto generated will be exclude by source control in the pending changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We will check it out and confirm whether this solution works.

Comment: Hi Ramesh Annadurai  Hope you are doing well. Any update on this issue. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: We have tried this solution, still we are facing the issue.

Comment: still you didn't find a solution @RameshAnnadurai ?? .. i face the same issue with TFSC in Mac, i have lates vs and latest mac os vs and latest xcode

Comment: @ahmedroshdy Still the issue is there.