# Core library project not added to DevOps from VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, tfs

I have a solution with 35 different projects in it (.NET 4.8). We are moving sections over to Core 3.1 now and needed to add few netcore libraries to the solution. 
For some reason the project files are not getting added to source control:

[image]

All projects under "Resources" folder does not get added to DevOps (the files needed to be manually added) but the project (also netcore) one folder above (Core) get's added.. I have searched for about 2 hrs now on the internet but not found a hint on what the problem is.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid these files `.Rescources` **are ignored in TFVC by default**.

Just check the "LocalItemExclusions.config" file under the path `"C:\Users\youraccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Configuration\VersionControl" folder and open"`. 
(There may several folders named like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, you need to make sure open the folder that match your TFS version.)

You could see that these folder and files types are ignored  and they are defined in that file.

[image]

Either manually add them or override this for particular folders by creating a `.tfignore file`.

Detail steps about how to create the ignore file, please take a look at here: [Visual Studio 2015 TFS .tfignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768954/visual-studio-2015-tfs-tfignore-file/36784750#36784750)

Comment: Also if you use Git look in the .gitignore file for the same exclusions and remove them.